# Detecting external Azure AD users with ASP.Net Core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

Users that are authenticated against my AzureAD tenant can access my ASP.Net Core 2.2 web app. I can get their UPN in controllers like this: `this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value`

Problem is when guest (external) users log in. Above will fail because they have no UPN claim. I can find no property or claim on the User object that indicates if the user is a Member of my tenant.

What is the proper way to detect if a user is a guest user?

Comment: I can't remember it exactly off the top of my head, but their home tenant id was in one of the claims (idp, issuer etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @juunas said , you can check the `idp` claim :

[image]

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims

You can get the claims value and check user account not in the same tenant  :

```
var idp = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider")?.Value;

if (idp!=null)
{
   //user is not in same tenant
}
```

In additon , if you want to get `iss` claim which identifies the security token service (STS) that constructs and returns the token , you can set the middleware to map the claim by :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.ClaimActions.Remove("iss");
});
```

And get the issuer by :

```
var issuer = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "iss")?.Value;
```